# Javascript - How to add objects to column array in kendo ui grid dynamically?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to generate objects in the columns array as the heading implies, although I haven't found a working method.

```
alert( "Value 1: " + temporaryArray[1] + " - " + finalArray[1].values ); 
alert( "Value 2: " + temporaryArray[2] + " - " + finalArray[2].values ); 
var myGrid =  $("#grid").kendoGrid( 
{
    columns: 
    [
        {
            title: temporaryArray[0] + " ",
            field: gridArray[0].values + " "
        }
    ],
    dataSource: 
    {
        data:finalArray,
        pageSize:10
    },
    scrollable:false,
    pageable:true 
});
```

I've tried the following to add the object:

```
for( var x = 0; x < finalArray.length; x++ )
{
    myGrid[columns] = { temporaryArray[x]:finalArray[x] };
}
```

*And*

```
for( var x = 0; x < finalArray.length; x++ )
{
    myGrid.columns[values]= finalArray[x].values;
}
```

**with no success...**

The following looks like an array of objects inside of the object which I want to achieve dynamically:

```
columns: 
[
    {
        title: temporaryArray[0] + " ",
        field: gridArray[0].values + " "
    },
    {
        title: temporaryArray[1] + " ",
        field: gridArray[1].values + " "
    },
    {
        title: temporaryArray[2] + " ",
        field: gridArray[2].values + " "
    }
],
```

*For example:*

```
for( var x = 0; x < finalArray.length; x++ )
{
    myGrid[columns] = { temporaryArray[x]:finalArray[x] };
}
```

*I want to generate the objects using a for loop to generate an array of objects inside the column array.*

What I want to know is, whether this is possible to do dynamically? or just possible at all without hard coding it?

Comment: Above part is done, Please find next question posted below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it. Lets have the Titles stored in `titleDefs` and the `field` name in `fieldDef`. Then you should do:

```
// Title Definitions
var titleDefs = [
    "First Name", "Last Name", "Title"
];
// Field Definition
var fieldDefs = [
    "FirstName", "LastName", "Title"
];
// Lets compute column definition
var columnDefs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < titleDefs.length; i++) {
    columnDefs.push({ title : titleDefs[i], field: fieldDefs[i] });
}
// Now, create the grid using columnDefs as argument
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data    : dataArray,
        pageSize: 10
    },
    columns   : columnDefs
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

**NOTE**: In this example I've defined a DataSource that is a JavaScript `array` in memory but you can get the data from a server changing the `DataSource` definition.

**NOTE**: In your code, you were adding extra white space to the `title` definition and that is not correct: column definitions are JavaScript code and not `strings` so you don't have to format it as you were going to display it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and for the extra note. I will keep that in mind. Everything is working now.

Comment: I've found that with the above code that when you add more values than there titles, blank titles are generated for fields. How can I add more values to already made columns?

Comment: In my code I iterate on `columnsDef.length` so I cannot add more `titles` than row values. Can you post the actual code in JSFiddle for showing me what you have?

Comment: Seeing that I'm getting my data from an xml file, I only posted the javascript coding at http://jsfiddle.net/jLsjk/1/. I have 2 arrays, One for the grid titles and one for the field values. The title consits of any number of fields between 3 and 7, which is calculated by JS, whereas the field value array consists of +-hundreds of values. The code that I am currently using, is merely looping the same row of data through the entire grid. thanks...

Comment: So _grid titles_ is only needed for computing `columns` definition in the `grid` whereas _field values_ are needed for the `DataSource`, right? Do you know that a `DataSource` might be an XML? See http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/xml-data.html

Comment: Since you have alerts in the code displaying intermediate arrays I assume that they are what you expected, right? It would help me if you can update Fiddle and instead of computing `gridArray` and `newArray` put some actual data (few, I don't need hundreds of rows)?  It is to make sure that the structure is what I understood since I'm seeing something strange.

Comment: Thats correct and yes I am aware. I have tried various methods, but the reason why they cannot be implemented is that I am using the xml data to generate an accordion with a grid in each of the tabs. I know of one way this can work with the currently used coding. That is to split the data into an array for each column, which is an unnecessary long method.

Comment: Everything worked accordingly until the last alert message. I have replaced the code on http://jsfiddle.net/jLsjk/1/ with the code on http://jsfiddle.net/jLsjk/2/ which has the 2 example arrays. Although I see, there is a slight problem to the code as it is not working.

Comment: Both arrays are incorrect, they should either be an array of `strings` (no curly brackets `{}`) or they should objects and then each element should have a field name.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for all the help. Everything is working.