# Javascript - Dynamic number of rows giving an error

Tags: javascript, grid, kendo-ui, calculated-columns

I have previously posted a question about this code to [generate a kendo grid dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15779973/2236074).

The current problem I have now, even when I hardcode the number of columns like so:

```
var numberOfRows = 2;
var numberOfColumns = 12;
var columnsPerRow = numberOfColumns/numberOfRows;
```

Is that I get the error :

[image]

```
First of all, what does this mean?
```

The columnsPerRow is used like so:

```
var columnDefs = [];
counter = 0;

var arrayData = [];
for( var x = 0; x < result.length-1; x=x+Math.floor(columnsPerRow)+1 )
{
    var tempArr = new Array();

    for( var y = 0; y < columnsPerRow; y++ )
    {
        var num = x + y;
        tempArr.push(result[num]);
    }
    arrayData.push(tempArr);
}
var dataTitles = [];
for( var x = 0; x < titleArray.length; x++ )
{
    var head = "";
    head = titleArray[x];
    head = head.replace(/ /g,"");
    dataTitles.push(head);
}

var counter = 0;
var columnDefs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < columnsPerRow.length; i++) 
{
    if (counter == (columnsPerRow - 1)) 
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
    columnDefs.push({ field: dataTitles[counter], template: result[i].value });
    counter++;
}
```

The grid is displayed as so:

[image]

and when I hide the column variables like so:

```
/*var numberOfRows = 2;
var numberOfColumns = 12;
var columnsPerRow = numberOfColumns/numberOfRows;*/
```

the output looks as it's supposed to:

[image]

but then null values are used for the number of columns, thus the for loop does not loop.

Except that the grid does not display the data.

I have placed all my javascript and html in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sWue/2/). Although it's not working in the fiddle. 
There might be some unused code. I'm busy removing it as I go along.

I've got these files attached:

```
<link href='assets/css/kendo.custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='assets/css/kendo.common.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<link href='assets/css/kendo.default.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src='assets/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='assets/js/kendo.all.min.js'></script>
```

and how can I fix this issue that data will be displayed in the grid?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks...

Comment: In the fiddle that you have provided, there is no `tableTitle` array provided which causes an error... I have updated the fiddle with some `tableTitle` test array an it seems to work (except for styling, but I guess that it is because I have not the `kendo.custom.css` stylesheet) : http://jsfiddle.net/5sWue/4/.

Comment: Thanks @SamuelCaillerie , although I found that that was not the only problem. Because of all the changes I made trying to simplify the coding, I forgot to make some slight changes as I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my problem was in this for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < columnsPerRow.length; i++) 
{
    if (counter == (columnsPerRow - 1)) 
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
    columnDefs.push({ field: dataTitles[counter], template: result[i].values });
    counter++;
}
```

The problems were as follows:

```
i < columnsPerRow.length
```

should be

```
i < columnsPerRow
```

and

```
columnDefs.push({ field: dataTitles[counter], template: result[i].values
```

should be

```
columnDefs.push({ field: dataTitles[counter], template: result[i]
```

and as  [@Samuel Caillerie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127669/samuel-caillerie) posted above, `tableTitle` needs to be added, which is an array that stores the headers.