# Angular 2 Kendo Grid from array of string

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm developing app with Angular 2 + Kendo UI.

So, I have array of paths to images and I want to show it in table form.
I want instead of 1 column in a table row show 5 columns in a table row.

Can I do that? If yes, then how would look **kendo grid html template** and **data** for it?

Comment: Not sure about Angular implementation, but it is possible to [construct a column array based on an array in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15780538/6224482).. Should just be a case on combining a column [`template`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/column-template-export) implementation along with this. Here is an article about [hyperlinks within the template](http://www.telerik.com/forums/template-column-with-an-anchor-tag-or-other-hyperlink-example) aswell. And here is an example using [Angular2](http://dojo.telerik.com/AtURa). Hope this helps

Comment: What data do you want the five columns to contain?

Comment: I want to place there string 'url'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the result is the following:

HTML template (table header is hidden):

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="{{column}}" [headerClass]="'hidden'">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <img *ngIf="dataItem[column].avatarUri != null" [src]="dataItem[column].avatarUri" [alt]="dataItem[column].keywords" />
             </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

TypeScript component:

```
gridData: any[];
columns: string[] = ["column0", "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"];

ngOnInit() {
    this.avatarService.getAvatars()
        .subscribe((avatars: Array<Avatar>) => {
            this.gridData = [];
            let i = 0;
            while (i < avatars.length) {
                let obj = {};
                for (let column of this.columns) {
                    obj[column] = {
                        avatarUri: i >= avatars.length ? null : avatars[i].avatarUri,
                        keywords: i >= avatars.length ? null : avatars[i].keywords
                    };
                    i++;
                }
                this.gridData.push(obj);
            }
        });
}
```

Also helped that link with [dynamic columns](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/#toc-hidden-state).